# "StructField" object has no attribute - "_get_object_id"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-emr

I was trying to evaluate a random forest model by computing Precision/Recall (PR) and Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC) values using `BinaryClassificationMetrics` from `pyspark.mllib.evaluation`, but I keep getting a `'StructField' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'`
error.   I am using Jupyter notebook on a cluster on Amazon EMR, with optional packages Livy, TensorFlow and Spark (Sparkmagic, Pyspark); everything else is just the default.

The following code reproduces the error for me:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext   
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession   
import pyspark
from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import BinaryClassificationMetrics

a = sc.parallelize([
    (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), 
    (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), 
    (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), 
    (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), 
    (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0)
])  

metrics = BinaryClassificationMetrics(a)
```

This is the error I get:

```
'StructField' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'  
Traceback (most recent call last):    
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/evaluation.py", line 52, in __init__ StructField("label", DoubleType(), nullable=False)]))    
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 302, in createDataFramereturn self.sparkSession.createDataFrame(data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)  
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1248, in __call__args_command, temp_args = self._build_args(*args)    
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1212, in _build_args (new_args, temp_args) = self._get_args(args)   
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1199, in _get_args temp_arg converter.convert(arg,self.gateway_client)
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.1 src.zip/py4j/java_collections.py", line 501, in convert java_list.add(element)
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1248, in __call__args_command, temp_args = self._build_args(*args)  
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1218, in _build_args [get_command_part(arg, self.pool) for arg in new_args])   
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 298, in get_command_part command_part = REFERENCE_TYPE + parameter._get_object_id()  
AttributeError: 'StructField' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

Comment: Please include the import statement for `BinaryClassificationMetrics`. I ran your code with `from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import BinaryClassificationMetrics` and I could not recreate your error.

Comment: Thanks. I just included it. I am afraid that I also should have mentioned that I am using Jupyter notebook on a cluster on Amazon EMR, with optional packages Livy, TensorFlow and Spark; everything else is just the default.

Comment: Hi @lilbludot,did you solve this? I am having exactly the same error with the same set-up as yours. It works locally.

Comment: No. I still have not gotten it to work.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on Amazon EMR. I copy the example code in the docs and source code and get: AttributeError: 'StructField' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'